# Apache2 and context path for virtual host with Django and AngularJS

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualhost

I had the following working Django configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /MyDjangoProjectFolder

<Directory /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject>
   <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /base_context_path/static/ /MyDjangoProjectFolder/static/

<Directory /MyDjangoProjectFolder/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Django responds on `<ip>/base_context_path/rest` (for rest APIs invoked by the frontend) and `<ip>/base_context_path/admin` (for administration, which uses base_context_path/static).
So everything needed by Django is on `<ip>/base_context_path/*`.

Now I need to deploy a website developed in Angular on this same Apache2, so I am trying to understand how to make it work. I have a domain name for this website (mydomainname.org), but not a dedicated one for the django application. When visiting my domain name, I would expect my website to appear.

This is my attempt for my website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainname.org
    DocumentRoot /MyWebSiteFolder
    DirectoryIndex index.html
 <Directory "/MyWebSiteFolder">
# redirect rules for managing AngularJS
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It does not work (403).

For my Django application, this is the virtual host I created, which does not work as well (403):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomainname
Alias /base_context_path/static/ /MyDjangoProjectFolder/static

WSGIScriptAlias / /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess MyDjangoProject python-path=/MyDjangoProjectFolder:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup MyDjangoProject


<Directory /MyDjangoProjectFolder/static>
        Options -Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So I am kind of stuck.

Comment: I would recommend using nginx with django/uwsgi. If you want to try have a look at this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Is that a typo for your ServerName in the django virtualhost config?  I expected it to be your fully qualified domain name...  (And I assume you've closed the virtualhost tag too.)

Answer (score 1):

For the *Directory* you need to add the follow directive:

```
  Require all granted
```

or some equivalent for the access to the directory. Apache might not have access to view that directory or be configured to have access to it. You also need to make sure that Apache has permissions to read, write and execute.

Also check the **apache** logs for additional information on the error (403) that is happening.

*I would also recommend, like Aki003, using **nginx** as it is easier to configure and use with uwsgi.*

Answer (score 1):

For your Django app to work under Apache, you should have `mod_wsgi` installed (it is recommend to use CMMI method so that you make sure you compile it for the same python version you are using to create the virtual environment).

If you don't have httpd.conf file, edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and write this line:

`Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

And proceed to create `httpd.conf` and inside it add the following content:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIPythonHome /some/path/where/is/an/empty/venv

Alias /static/ /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject/static/

<Directory /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject/wsgi.py process-group=MyDjangoProject

<Directory /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

(side note): You might also want to include the security headers here:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-XSS-Protection 1;mode=block
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

Your VirtualHost file should look like that:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIDaemonProcess MyDjangoProject 
    WSGIProcessGroup MyDjangoProject

    WSGIScriptAlias / /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject/wsgi.py 

    <Directory /MyDjangoProjectFolder/MyDjangoProject>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

According to `mod_wsgi` documentation, this is the configuration for using the Daemon Mode for multiple apps (you might want to add or test other apps, so this is a good preparation).

`/some/path/where/is/an/empty/venv` is the path where you would want to create an empty virtual environment (using `virtualenv` !! so that you have access to `activate_this.py` script !!) 
Make sure to create and activate another virtual environment inside you django project where you will install all your dependencies.

You might want to do so because when you are activating virtual environment from within the WSGI file, only the site-packages directory from the python virtual environment is being used.
If you by any chance omit to install a package from `requirements.txt`, but those are installed in the main python installation, they would be used from there and if there is a wrong version or has different dependencies, you might get some errors.

Next step is to modify `wsgi.py` by adding those lines first (before any import):

```py
python_home='/path/to/the/MyDjangoProjectFolder/venv'
activate_this=python_home+'/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
        exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

so that when mod_wsgi is parsing this file, to activate the virtual environment where all your dependecies are, in order to function properly.

Also, in the same file(`wsgi.py`), add the path to your django project to sys path:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/MyDjangoProjectFolder')
```

Also, do not forget to set
`DEBUG = False` and edit `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomainname.org']`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my setup template I use every time for Apache2.

```
    Apache2:
    sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
    cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

    sudo nano 000-default.conf

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        

        ErrorLog /home/user/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/user/site/access.log combined

        ServerName website.com
            ServerAlias www.website.com

        Alias /static /home/user/django_project/static
        <Directory /home/user/django_project/static>
            require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/user/django_project/media
        <Directory /home/user/django_project/media>
            require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /images /home/user/django_project/images
        <Directory /home/user/django_project/images>
            require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/user/django_project/folder_containing_settings>
            <files wsgi.py>
                require all granted
            </files>
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_project python-path=/home/user/django_project python-home=/home/user/django_project/env
        WSGIProcessGroup django_project
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/django_project/folder_containing_settings/wsgi.py


    </VirtualHost><span style="font-weight: 400;">


        
    sudo apachectl configtest
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to  create two configuration file one for django app and another for frontend app

first you can make it by domain and subdomain
frontend example.com
backend api.example.com

or you change
WSGIScriptAlias /  to WSGIScriptAlias /base_context_path

and fronted will by default